# Displaying two divs next to each other with space in between using css

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

How can I place two divs next to each other using css. I tried a few things on my own, but not sure where my mistakes are. Thanks!

css:

```
.posts{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.posts .col-md-6{
    padding-top: 14px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.posts .searchandlists{
    padding-top: 14px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /*float: right;*/
    /*padding-bottom: 14px;*/
}

.list-group{
    max-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

html:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <section class="row posts">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-3-offset></div>
<div class="container searchandlists"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? And `@extends` and `@section` aren't HTML. What are they from?

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap. I am using ```@extend``` and ```@section``` to combine a master html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's required to have one `.container` as the parent before you can use `.row` (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers).
2. `col-md-3-offset` is not in *bootstrap4*. Use `.offset-md-3` instead (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns).
3. I will personally use *bootstrap grid system* as the structure and customize the elements inside. I would not write custom styles on existing *bootstrap* elements, like what you did on `.post .col-md-6`, unless you know what you're doing.

I will prefer to have a layout like this:

```html
<section class="posts">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="searchandlists"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this ,approve answer if helps

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>123</title>
        <style>
            .box1{width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: red; float: left;}
            .box2{width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: blue; float: left; margin-left: 50px;}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten into the habit of using tables a lot.

```
    <section class="row posts">
<tr>
<td><div class="col-md-6 col-md-3-offset></div></td>
<td><div class="container searchandlists"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Even with separate div elements, the two items should show up side by side.  Hope it helps and cheers!

Comment: I would recommend avoiding tables unless you are displaying data. Tables are not meant to be used for positioning of UI elements, and it defeats the purpose of using a grid based CSS system.